# How to Create Crud Easy Step in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, crud

Do you guys have a *smart and easy* way to make crud in **laravel framework**?

Hot to make crud in laravel easy And fast,i tery step step in official website laravel but i do not understand.
Please let me know the easy steps i understands Thanks.

Comment: [Link 1](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/crud-create-read-update-delete-example-in-laravel-52-from-scratchexample.html), [Link 2](http://www.dunebook.com/creating-a-simple-crud-application-in-laravel/)

Comment: go through https://laracasts.com/

Comment: Search on [Google](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjaoemqkb_TAhXCqo8KHYlLBVYQPAgD#safe=strict&hl=en&q=Simple+CRUD+Laravel+5.4) with proper keywords, you will find various examples and tutorials of it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you guys have a smart and easy way to make crud in laravel framework?

Hot to make crud in laravel easy And fast,i tery step step in official website laravel but i do not understand. Please let me know the easy steps i understands Thanks.

I have the small totarial, this can help you !

//////////// FUNDAMENTAL ////////////

1. Create LARAVEL Project
   composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel Airport
2. Create Database in PhpMyAdmin
3. Open project file in cmd / powerShell
4. Create Table with php artisan
   php artisan make:migration create_flight_table
5. Open your text editor and edit **.env**

   DB_CONNECTION=mysql

   DB_HOST=localhost

   DB_DATABASE=airport

   DB_USERNAME=root

   DB_PASSWORD=
6. Go to folder database>migration , delete user and pasword table ,open flight_table file and edit

public function up()

```
{

    Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('name');

    $table->string('airline');

    $table->timestamps();

    });

}



public function down()

{

    Schema::drop('flights');

}
```

8. Migrate the table in cmd or powerShell

   php artisan migrate
9. Check your table in PhpMyAdmin

==============================================================================

//////////// MODEL VIEW CONTROLLER ////////////

10. Create Model in cmd or powerShell

    php artisan make:model Tower

    protected $table = 'flights';
11. Create View in folder resources>views

    create new folder called hangar

    create index.blade.php

    create edit.blade.php

    create create.blade.php
12. Create Controller in cmd or powerShell

    php artisan make:controller flightController --resource
13. Open and edit your controller

use App\model;

public function index()

```
 {

     $vars = Tower::all();

     return view('hangar.index',['var' => $vars]);
 }
```

14. Go to folder routes, Open and edit web.php

    Route::resource('main', 'flightController');
15. Insert data in PhpMyAdmin
16. Open and edit your index.blade

## VIEW

CREATE

@foreach($var as $var)

```
<p> {{ $var->name}} </p>

<p> {{ $var->airline}} </p>

{{ date('F d, Y', strtotime($var->created_at))}}<br><br>

<hr>
```

@endforeach

17. Run this command in cmd or powerShell

    php artisan serve
18. copy paste this

## http://127.0.0.1:8000/main

//////////// CRUD ////////////

//////////// CREATE ////////////

19. Open and edit your controller

public function create()

```
{

    return view('hangar.create');

}
```

20. Open and edit create.blade.php

@if(count($errors)>0)

```
<ul>

    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)

        <li>

            {{$error}}

        </li>

    @endforeach

</ul>
```

@endif

## CREATE

21. Open and edit controller

public function store(Request $request)

```
{
    $this->validate($request, [

       'name' => 'required', 'airline' => 'required', 

    ]);

    $var = new asd;

    $var->name = $request->name;

    $var->airline = $request->airline;

    $var->save();

    return redirect('main');

}
```

==============================================================================

//////////// UPDATE ////////////

22. Open and edit controller

public function edit($id)

```
{

    $var = Tower::find($id);

    if(!$var){

        abort(404);

    }


    return view('hangar.edit')->with('var', $var);

}
```

23. Open and edit edit.blade

@if(count($errors)>0)

```
<ul>

    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)

        <li>

            {{$error}}

        </li>

    @endforeach

</ul>
```

@endif

## EDIT

id}}" method="post">

    plane}}" placeholder="plane">


    airline}}" 
placeholder="airline">

24. Open and edit controller

public function update(Request $request, $id)

```
{

    $this->validate($request, [

       'name' => 'required', 'airline' => 'required',

    ]);

    $var = Tower::find($id);

    $var ->name = $request->name;

    $var ->airline = $request->airline;

    $var ->save();

    return redirect('main');

}
```

26. Open and edit index.blade

id}}/edit"> EDIT

==============================================================================

//////////// DELETE ////////////

25. Open and edit Controller

public function destroy($id)

```
{

    $var = Tower::find($id);

    $var ->delete();

    return redirect('main');

}
```

26. Open and edit index.blade

id}}" method="post">

//////////// FINISH ////////////

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install Laravel
If you haven't installed Laravel, you can do so using Composer. Open your terminal and run:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel your-crud-app
```

Step 2: Set Up Database Configuration
Edit the .env file in your project directory to configure your database connection details.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=your_database_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_database_password
```

Step 3:Run the migration to create the necessary tables:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Step 4: Create a Model
Generate a model for your CRUD resource. For example, if you're creating a CRUD for a "Post," run:

```
php artisan make:model Post -m
```

Step 5: Edit the Migration File
In the generated migration file (located in the database/migrations directory), define the table columns you need for your CRUD resource.

Step 5--1: Run the Migration
Run the migration to create the table in your database:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Step 6: Create a Controller
Generate a controller for your CRUD resource. For example, for a "Post" controller:

```
php artisan make:controller PostController
```

Step 7: Implement CRUD Operations in the Controller
Edit the PostController.php file to include the logic for CRUD operations. Here's a simplified example:

```
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Post::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Post::destroy($id);
        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }
}
```

Step 8: Create Views
Create Blade views for your CRUD operations. For example:

```
resources/views/posts/index.blade.php
resources/views/posts/create.blade.php
resources/views/posts/show.blade.php
resources/views/posts/edit.blade.php
```

Step 9: Define Routes
Define routes in the routes/web.php file to map URLs to your controller methods:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

Step 10: Run Your Laravel Application

```
php artisan serve
```

hit URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts` in your browser to see your CRUD application in action.